# How do you add custom attributes to Customer Groups in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, attributes

We're on Magento CE 1.7.0.0, and we're trying to add new attributes to the Customer Group entities. We've successfully added custom attributes to Customers using the following install script:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$setup = Mage::getModel('customer/entity_setup', 'core_setup');

$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'ussco_account_number', array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'USSCO Account Number',
    'note' => 'Leave blank for default',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 0,
    'default' => '',
    'visible_on_front' => 0,
    'source' =>   NULL,
));

Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('customer', 'ussco_account_number')
    ->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer'))
    ->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

Has anyone had any luck doing something similar with Customer Groups, rather than customers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you take a look at the sql installer/update scripts you will find something like this:

```
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('customer/customer_group'))
    ->addColumn('customer_group_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
        ), 'Customer Group Id')
    ->addColumn('customer_group_code', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 32, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Customer Group Code')
    ->addColumn('tax_class_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '0',
        ), 'Tax Class Id')
    ->setComment('Customer Group');
```

As you can see its a simple mysql4 table and you simply need to add a column to the group. It is not EAV so you dont work with attributes on that one!

The new colum will not show up in the form or grid! You have to add this manually via observer or rewriting `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Group_Edit_Form` or `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Group_Grid` by adding something like this for e.g text field:

```
$fieldset->addField('your_column', 'text',
    array(
        'name'  => 'Your_Column',
        'label' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Tax Class'),
        'title' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Tax Class'),
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true
    )
);
```

Comment: to clarify, if I use similar code to add a column to the customer groups, they'll show up in the admin like `Tax Class`, correct?

Comment: How would you get this column to display on the users Dashboard?

Comment: Scratch that, it does show up.... When I input it directly into the DB. It just doesn't save the information when I edit the Customer Group... Any thoughts?

Comment: @AJMaxwell You have to use "Flush Cache Storage" - I just lost about an hour on this. My custom values would not save... Magento stores things like table structure outside of the typical caches. As soon as I flushed the cache storage, it worked just fine. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I 've had the same need to include a field in customer_group. I want to add here my sql script to add some custom fields into **customer_group**

```
$installer = $this; 
$installer->startSetup();   

$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('customer_group'), 'my_custom_field1', 'varchar(100)');
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('customer_group'), 'my_custom_field2', 'varchar(100)');

$installer->endSetup();
```

Regards