# Attribute sets for customers - Magento

Tags: magento, attributes, set

I want to add an attribute set (as those used for products) for each group of customer. Is this possible? How can I do it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at this question dealing with adding attributes to the customer entity http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961290/adding-attributes-to-customer-entity/5962237#5962237

Comment: Thanks, but... that's not what I was looking for...

Comment: Have a look in this link may be you ll find the answer...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241595/how-do-you-add-custom-attributes-to-customer-groups-in-magento

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this isn't possible out of the box. You will need to create a custom module for this.

Comment: I couldn't find anything about it on internet.